# Opening Chrome settings page in Terminal

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

I'd like to use Terminal on Mac's `open` command to open a link to a page in Chrome's settings. Currently, I'm doing something like this:

`alias chrome_settings='open -a "Google Chrome" chrome://settings/'`

But I get a message stating *The file /Users/codes/chrome:/settings does not exist.*

How is it being interpreted as a file, when I intend for it to be opened as a web page? I've also tried passing it in as an argument, using `open -a "Google Chrome" --args chrome://settings/`, but this doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Maybe try using just `open -a "Google Chrome" --args 'settings'` ...